# Techniques to focus a specific list item?

Tags: android, ios

I am playing around with website design and am having trouble letting a user know a specific item in the list is special / important / requires attention.

I have tried increasing the size of the item, but this does not scale well onto smaller devices (such as phones).

Anyone have any suggestions or know of a website/blog/video where I can learn about these types of techniques?

NOTE: Each list item has a picture and some text.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a sample we can see? You can post this as a [critique question](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work) here and we can try to help.

Comment: Unfortunately for confidentiality reasons I cannot post the exact work, but [this](https://lh3.ggpht.com/ChRH_l58oKoGPAzTfaUKWd1zRQXwAy0Y827DV-H1xpV2CbsYpvdJSdghf32Ug3u-AyI=h900) is very close to what mine looks like.  My goal is to then get the user's attention to the 'now playing' piece of media.

Comment: That's ok, the link gives a  good idea of the interface. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of a few options. Pardon the simple samples:

**1.** Highlight the item as a block or add a border

[image]

**2.** Add an element ,for example an icon

[image]

**3.** Change the color of the title

[image]

Comment: I like 3 the most.  I immediately want to look at that one!  Do you know of any additional techniques if the item I am trying to bring focus to is always at the top of the list?

Comment: @Mr_Skid_Marks Maybe a line separating it from the rest of the list? Or some white space and a little something in the middle, three dots, a tiny icon...

Comment: I will definitely give it a shot! Thanks for your input